# How can I manipulate a string into multiple ints?

Tags: powershell, get-wmiobject

I am a student and working on a script to monitor some rudimental information of servers in my company. This following script outputs the CPU percentage and works on PCs with one single CPU. 
The output on my computer would look like this:

> 60

This is what my code looks like:

```
$cpuload = Get-WmiObject win32_processor -computername $server
[string]$load = $cpuload.loadpercentage
[int]$intload = $load #convert string to int so I can make calculations
```

But some servers have multiple CPUs the output then looks like this:

> 45 23

How can I convert this output into multiple int variables so that I can make calculations with the CPU percentage separately? Or is there even a better way to solve it?

Comment: `loadpercentage` is already an `int`.  You cast to a `string`, then back to an `int`.  If `loadpercentage` is an array of ints (which it will be if you have multiple CPUs), then get the avarage like this:  `$load = ($cpuload.loadpercentage | Measure-Object -Average).Average`